# Thymeleaf: Access Environment bean

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to access the environment properties:

```
<h1 th:text="${@environment.getProperty('site.name1')}">
                                    <span th:text="${@environment.getProperty('site.name2')}"></span>
                                </h1>
```

but I don't get anything for `site.name2` even it exists in `application.property` file

here my application.properties file:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false

site.name1=plats
site.name2=bruts


spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8

spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=1000MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=1000MB
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true

server.port=8080
```

This is how it looks using:

```
<h1>Plats
<span class="muellerhoff">Bruts</span>
</h1>
```

[image]

and with:

```
    <h1>
<span th:text="${@environment.getProperty('site.name1')}"></span>
                                        <br/>
<span class="muellerhoff"  th:text="${@environment.getProperty('site.name2')}"></span>
</h1>
```

[image]

Comment: It's fine for site.name1, but not for site.name2 (?!)

Comment: You have content inside your `<h1>` tag - in this case, the `<span>` tag.  Everything inside the `<h1>` tag gets replaced by the results of the H1's `th:text` value. That is why the `name2` value disappears. The entire `<span>` tag is removed.  I have withdrawn my duplicate vote - it is not relevant - sorry about that.

Comment: In these cases, I like to start with the end-result: What do you need your final HTML to look like? Then you can work backwards from that to create the relevant Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end goal is HTML as follows:

```html
<h1>Plats
    <span class="muellerhoff">Bruts</span>
</h1>
```

You can use `<th:block>` in this case, to handle the `name1` value. The block tag will not appear in the final HTML.

```html
<h1> 
    <th:block th:text="${@environment.getProperty('site.name1')}"></th:block>
    <span class="muellerhoff" th:text="${@environment.getProperty('site.name2')}"></span>
</h1>
```

More info about the `th:block` tag can be found [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#synthetic-thblock-tag).